# types issue resulting in bad signature when integrating assets pallet into node-template derived chain

Tags: substrate

Having an issue with types, i think, in implementing pallet_assets into the node template. When trying to apply the general idea from https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/efd262f1a791be0a7986b25bd302338a590b46d3/frame/assets#simple-code-snippet
see -> https://github.com/Greenetwork/BLX_chain/blob/1a2f1f0f22f72c1795ff5900a62c8ccee69dbc23/pallets/allocator/src/lib.rs#L126
but including atokens: T::Balance causes a bad signature error. Am i missing some type in the frontend? I tried "atoken" : "Balance" with no luck

Comment: First off, I would encourage you to move to FRAME v2 as syntax is more clear and supported - [here is the pallet template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/master/pallets/template/src/)

Are you able to end any other signed extrinsics? What error exactly and where are you getting it (the apps UI I presume)?

Comment: FRAME v2 is on the docket for sure. I am able to send all other signed extrinsics from multiple other pallets.    
  
Yes, for ease of development I am using apps UI and then implementing in a modified front-end-template later.  

exact error is: `submitAndWatchExtrinsic(extrinsic: Extrinsic): ExtrinsicStatus:: 1010: Invalid Transaction: Transaction has a bad signature`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pallet_assets's [balance](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/efd262f1a791be0a7986b25bd302338a590b46d3/frame/assets/src/lib.rs#L177) is not the same as balances's [balance](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/efd262f1a791be0a7986b25bd302338a590b46d3/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L195)

`"atoken" : "Balance"` custom type definition was not correct. *atoken* was the variable not the type.

I renamed pallet_assets's balance to *balance1* and used `"Balance1": "u64",` in the types.json

Comment: Congrats on the solution! Although I _think_ there is a "better" way in concretely setting the type -  https://substrate.dev/recipes/pallet-coupling.html has some hints.

Comment: `atokens: <T as pallet_assets::Config>::Balance`  should do it for you in the [place you referenced](https://github.com/Greenetwork/BLX_chain/blob/1a2f1f0f22f72c1795ff5900a62c8ccee69dbc23/pallets/allocator/src/lib.rs#L126) I think.